Possible French horror movie with schizophrenic protagonist
I am looking for a horror movie that I do remember a few things about, some of them I am uncertain of. What I believe to know is this:

The protagonist suffers from schizophrenia and kills whores


The opening scene is about him getting a blowjob and then throwing out the severed head of the window of his car
The car is an old transporter, could be an old Renault or Citroen HY from the 1950's

The movie ends with a woman using a stone saw to cut through the windshield of a car
There is one scene where a person falls "into" a staircase, getting stuck with their head within the bars of the handrail


The protagonist then uses a piano to decapitate that trapped person


What I am not certain about is:

Related to France: Plays there, has french actors or a french director
First word in title was something like "total" or "absolute"

Other facts:

The movie was in color (not b/w)
Release date, if I were to guess, 1995 or later


I found it! The movie is called High Tension (french: Haute Tension)

French college students, Marie and Alex, head to Alex's secluded farmhouse in hopes of studying for their exams without distractions. While settling in, a man breaks into the home and brutally murders Alex's family while Marie tries to hide herself from the killer. When the killer binds and kidnaps Alex, Marie follows him, attempting saving her friend and, along the way, running into some dangerous obstacles. 






You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

I love this movie!
